# Drupal Node Id reflection

Tags: 7

What's the preferred way to get the current Node ID while inside a Drupal module function, without passing it in?

Adding more text, because StackOverflow won't post short questions:

Ideally, I'd like some kind of reflection function, where I can simply request the NID of the  node being served in the stack trace. Since Drupal revolves around serving nodes, it stands to reason that there should be some kind of reflection function that makes "the node I'm operating on presently, or NULL if I'm not operating on a node", available at all times.

The best discussions I've found pull the NID out of the URL. This strikes me as a backwards way of recovering the NID, and fragile, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get the current viewed nodes id you should be able to do like this:

```
// check so we're really viewing a node
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  // grab the nid for the node
  $nid = arg(1);
  // you could also try to load the node to make
  // sure the supplied nid is valid
  if (node_load($nid) == FALSE) {
    // failed to load the node
  }
}
```

In the case of an ajax request I guess you really ***should*** supply the `nid` as an argument:

```
function <MODULE>_menu() {
  $items['sample/%1'] = array(
    'page callback' => '<MODULE>_sample',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  };
  return $items;
}

function <MODULE>_sample($nid) {
  // use the supplied nid here
  $node = node_load($nid);
  if ($node) {
    // do something with the loaded node
  }
}

jQuery('#output').load('sample/21');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking to get away from. Not only is this fragile, breaking for sites that pass the arguments differently, but the arguments aren't accessible when you're 3 function calls deep, in AJAX callbacks, which is when I suddenly find myself needing to know the original NID that triggered the call. Of course, I could modify the signature of every function that was called to get this far, adding the NID in to pass it along, and then every function that called those functions to catch them up to the signature change... but that would be bad.

Comment: @baudot - I updated my answer. Can you give an example of a site that doesn't use the `node/%1` in the url even if the do use pathauto or similar?

Comment: @baudot Getting the node ID from the current router path (not the URL) is the preferred method. The canonical router path for a node is `node/%`, as defined in `node_menu()`, and unless you're doing something particularly custom like overriding the entity URI callback for the node entity type (and possibly even if you are), it's bulletproof. [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) is the related helper method. `$node = menu_get_object(); if ($node) { // you're on a node page, the ID is in $node->nid }`

Comment: I just noticed what you said about AJAX calls - the path for an AJAX call through the API is `system/ajax`, so you'll have to pass the node ID along manually for context, or get it from whatever form you're altering if that's your use case. Nothing you can do about that, it's how the web works. The concept of reflection doesn't apply here, because obviously the page containing the JS that makes the request to AJAX, and the AJAX request itself, are completely separate and cannot know about the variables prepared in the others request